# Create new spreadsheet via GDrive REST API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I want to create a new spreadsheet in Google Drive, using the V4 REST API in Javascript. I can write data to an existing one, since I have an id, like this, once oauthed:

```
var accessToken=gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
var str="https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/"+id+"/values/Sheet1!A1:E50?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED";
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("PUT",str);                                                                
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ accessToken);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

But I don't know how to create one from scratch in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that you want to create new Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Sample script :

```
var data = {"properties": {"title": "### filename of new spreadsheet ###"}}; // Added
var accessToken=gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
var str="https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets"; // Modified
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST",str); // Modified
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ accessToken);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

#### Note :

- If the error related to scopes occurs, please check the reference.
- `data` in this sample is very simple. So please modify it for your environment.

#### Reference :

- [spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new spreadsheet, you can follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create).

> Creates a spreadsheet, returning the newly created spreadsheet.

It requires one of the following OAuth scopes:

> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
>
> For more information, see the [Auth Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

For the sample code, see the example in the said documentation.